# Search txt file and return PC name if string exist

Tags: powershell

I probably should not have added the script I was trying to tweak as it might not have been the best choice to start with. I just knew it had to ability to get a string from a text file and return some result. Here is basically what I need. Wanting to add a variable such as this :$env:COMPUTERNAME
Each PC has a file in C:\someSoftware\version\ and it has a txt file.

Inside this text file, there is a version number formatted like: VER = 1.425.1

I wanting the script to tell me which computers are not version 1.425.1

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

```
$Path = "C:\Admin\"
$Text = "SomeText"
$PathArray = @()
$Results = "C:\temp\test.txt"

# This code snippet gets all the files in $Path that end in ".txt".

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.txt" |
Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} |

ForEach-Object {
  If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
    $PathArray += $_.FullName
    $PathArray += $_.FullName
  }
}

Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$PathArray | % {$_} | Out-File "C:\SearchString\Output.txt"
```

Comment: If you want to add the Hostname to the Array instead of the Filename, just do:
`$PathArrray += $env:computername`

Comment: You prepare var `$Result` and don't use it. Select-String can do it in one go: `(sls -Path "C:\Admin\*.txt" -Pattern "SomeText" -Simplematch).filename|Set-Content "C:\temp\test.txt"`

Comment: Paxz that looked promising but my results where not returning anything.

Comment: I tale that back Paxz! Look like your statement had an extra "r". Works like a champ after removal. Thanks